# Why google invisible recaptcha return bad JSON?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I have a problem with re-captcha invisible.
I think the response JSON is wrong, so the modal which contains the image choice won't display.

I follow this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible).

Here's the code I included:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6L...u" data-callback='onSubmit'>Re captcha</button>
```

The Url it request:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/userverify?k=6L...u
```

The JSON response:

```
)]}'
["uvresp", "03AOLTBLQJWPO3HSe...OB",1,120]
```

My onSubmit function:

```
function onSubmit(data, err) {
   console.log(data, err) // I get the token 
}
```

I excepted to see the modal, but nothing happen.

How can I avoid this bad response?

Comment: How does you `onSumbit` look like and do you have the required form which `onSubmit` will most likely execute?

Comment: Updated my question